# Vertical alignment of image, text, and tikz graphics in a table row

Tags: alignment

I have a table with three columns; one is a text column, one contains images, and the last one a tikz graphics. But I am not being able to vertically align them. Somewhat minimal code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=7.5in,paperheight=11in}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\animal}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, height=0.1\linewidth]{animal.png}\hspace{1em}}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\tikz{\path[draw, line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (0.6in, 0.6in)}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={X[0.1]XX[0.12]@{}},
        columns = {m},
        column{1} = {font=\Huge},
        hlines = {}{2-3}{},
    }
        \red{B} & \animal \animal \hspace{3em} \animal \animal \animal \animal \animal & \mybox\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

I have tried using the `valign=c` option from the `adjustbox` package. But that didn't also work.

Modification for `valign`:

```
\newcommand{\animal}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, height=0.1\linewidth, valign=c]{animal.png}\hspace{1em}}
```

Adjustbox output:

[image]

How may I solve this?

Edit: My question presentation has created some confusion. So, I am updating the code a bit. Now I have added the all the horizontal and vertical lines to make it easier to show my problem.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=7.5in,paperheight=11in}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\animal}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, height=0.1\linewidth]{animal.png}\hspace{1em}}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\tikz{\path[draw, line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (0.6in, 0.6in)}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={X[0.1, c]XX[0.12]@{}},
        columns = {m},
        column{1} = {font=\Huge},
        hlines = {}{1-3}{},
        vlines
    }
        \red{B} & \animal \animal \hspace{3em} \animal \animal \animal \animal \animal & \mybox\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My expected output:

[image]

Comment: How do you want them aligned exactly? What you need to do is think about the `baseline` of each. You can specify the baseline of the Ti*k*Z picture using the `baseline` option of the `tikzpicture` environment. The `tikzpicture` looks taller than the others, so you how should that difference be accommodated?

Comment: For the image specifying one prameter, e.g. `height` is sufficient ... perhaps that solves your problem already? Images are rescaled to meet said height.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the direction. I have been able to [vertically center the tikz image](https://imgur.com/n220J00) by tweaking the `baseline` key of the `tikz` command (haven't yet been able to solve for the 1st column). And to answer your query, I want to vertically align all columns in the center.

Comment: @MS-SPO In my original code, I have specified only the `width` key. In the MWE, I added the `height` key (along with `width`) to visually resemble my original output. [Here](https://imgur.com/pVQd0Sx) is an output of the MWE if I don't specify the `height` key.

Comment: @Imran: ok. However, the code you posted uses both parameters.

Comment: What's wrong with the alignment of the first? They look aligned in the image you posted.

Comment: @cfr The first column isn't vertically centered. The text in the 1st column is aligned to the bottom of the row.

Comment: In the images you posted, the first column has the same height as the second, doesn't it? And only the third column *looks* misaligned.

Comment: @cfr I am confused if I am using the word "align" properly. So, I have attached an image of the expected output. Hope that clears any confusion.

Comment: You are using 'align' fine. It just didn't occur to be 'B' was part of the row. I saw it as *outside* the tabular because the grey lines above and below said 'tabular here!' ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer ... but I don't think you're going to like it.

[image: aligned boxes and things]

The basic problem is that TeX aligns things to the baseline, but `tabulararry` isn't very clear about what exactly the various options and specifications do. (Or perhaps it is just a cross-referencing problem and the details are not with the explanations I found.) This means that what matters about some examples is left to the reader to determine. For example, it might not occur to somebody that it really matters whether the example contains multi-line text rather than, say, an image.

The rather substantive complication is the use of `\Huge` for a single column. This makes it harder to adjust things. In the code below, I've done this by measuring the height of `\Huge x` to get the 'x' height, half of which is what we want to adjust by. Note that if the first column contained `x` rather than `B`, we'd want half of half the 'x' height.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=7.5in,paperheight=11in}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newlength\mylength
\newlength\mylengtha
\newlength\mylengthb
\newcommand{\animal}{\raisebox{.5\mylengthb}{\begin{minipage}[c]{\mylength}\includegraphics[width=\mylengtha, height=\mylengtha]{animal.png}\end{minipage}\hspace{.05em}}}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\raisebox{.5\mylengthb}{\begin{minipage}[c]{\mylength}\tikz{\path[draw, line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (0.6in, 0.6in);}\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\mylength{.075\linewidth+1em}
\setlength\mylengtha{.075\linewidth}
\settoheight\mylengthb{\Huge x}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={X[0.1, c]XX[0.18,c]@{}},
      columns = {m},
      column{1} = {font=\Huge},
      hlines = {}{1-3}{},
      vlines
    }
    \red{B} & \animal \animal \hspace{2.5em} \animal \animal \animal \animal \animal & \mybox\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The effect of putting things in `minipage`s is to introduce some padding, so I've reduced various dimensions for the example.

If all this seems like a lot of work, I recommend `xcoffins`. The package is experimental, but the underlying programming layer isn't (so if the package disappears in a puff of smoke or gets turned into a frog or something, you could recreate the commands fairly easily - or somebody on this site could do so if you don't like `expl3`).

Off-topic but the use of `beamer` here seems somewhat egregious. Why are you using this class with `geometry`?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked perfectly. And about your question: the person I am working for wanted it this way (`beamer` class with this page size), so I used the `geometry` package (PS now I have found out that I didn't need to explicitly load the package).

Comment: @Imran Fair enough. Yes, I think `beamer` uses `geometry`. This just seemed an odd size for slides. There is also `article` mode, of course, but that's rather different. And `beamerposter`. But if that's what they want, that's what they want, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

`valign=M` and `\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]`.

```latex
\newcommand{\animal}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, height=0.1\linewidth, valign=M]{animal.png}\hspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]{\path[draw, line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (0.6in, 0.6in)}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. Using this code, however, doesn't align the vertically align the text in the 1st column. The output: https://imgur.com/XMc1ClA ; Desired output: https://imgur.com/AWMcA3q

Comment: @Imran You can try `\tikz[baseline=0.235in]`.

Answer (score 2):

With

- `tikz`with `[baseline]` in the first column
- `valign=M` (the Clara's answer)
- `tikz`with `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` in the 3rd column

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=7.5in,paperheight=11in}
\usepackage{showframe}%<-- comment 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    letter/.style={
    %draw,    
    red,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt
    }
}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\tikz [baseline]\node[letter] {#1};}%

\newcommand{\animal}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth, height=0.1\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}\hspace{1em}%
}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]{\path[draw, line width=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (0.6in, 0.6in)}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%<-- overfull 15pt
\begin{tblr}{
    %colspec={X[0.1, c]XX[0.12]@{}},%<-- overful with 0.12
    colspec={X[0.1,c]X[c]X[0.3,c]},%
    columns = {m},
    column{1} = {font=\Huge},
    hlines = {}{1-3}{},
    vlines,
}
    \red{B}&\fbox{\animal \animal \hspace{3em}  \animal \animal}  & \mybox\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]